# Windows 7 Keeps Changing the MBR on boot (grub2)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, laptop, mbr, grub

I installed Ubuntu in my new notebook. It originally comes with Windows 7 installed on it. Everything works nice however every time i boot into Windows7 the grub menu doesn't work any more. i can't boot into windows or ubuntu any more.

How do I stop this? Its rather annoying to have to boot, chroot and fix this problem everytime.

Comment: When your computer starts up, does it first show the windows boot loader and then take you to grub when you choose Ubuntu? Or is grub the only boot loader you see when your computer starts?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you wrote over your windows mbr. From what I understand, its best to have the windows boot loader load up grub and then  have grub let you get to Ubuntu.

First of all... I would make a backup of your system so you can always restore back to where you are right now. Some free backup tools:

- cloneZilla
- PING
- macrium reflect

I would then try a fixmbr from microsofts recovery consol as described [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true).

Once you have windows booting up properly, you have a few options options.

- You can avoid a lot of pain by using wubi to install ubuntu
- You can try to install Ubuntu again from a CD and see if there is an option to keep the windows boot loader.

This site has a lot of information. You might want to take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Answer (score 1):

i found the problem, looks like Dell DataSafe utility was trying to restore my mbr. I uninstall it and then restore the grub2 menu. Everything is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not expected behavior for windows 7. Is there "system restore" programs installed in the computer? If not then think about viruses...